# Docker build error "no such file or directory" when building a simple Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble building a really simple Dockerfile. Here's the content:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
```

Then, when I execute `docker build .`, I can see the `apt-get update` output and after retrieving the new list of packages, the command is returning this error:

> no such file or directory

I'm not quite sure why I get this error. Any idea?

Comment: It seems there's a regression in Docker 0.7.3. https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3451

Comment: That is only confirmed for Devicemapper. Are you using that, or the default AUFS ?

Comment: You  should run the docker build . command from the same directory which contains Dockerfile. For more information post the screenshots of the error for clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Dockerfile in the same level where you are trying to run `docker build` command?

the command structure is: `docker build <path/of/your/Dockerfile>`